# Using Option[string] in a string the cleanest way in Scala?

Tags: scala, string-formatting, option-type, simplify

I'm wondering if this little snippet of code:

```
val some = Some("string").getOrElse("")
val none = None.getOrElse("")

println(s"some $some none $none") -> some string none
```

Could be written cleaner? And I am mainly looking at the getOrElse part.

Can I use an Option in a String without having to use getOrElse?

Thanks for your input :)

Davey

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? This code could be cleaner with `val some = "string"; val none = "";` :-)

Comment: This is just an example of what I encounter for work, it's not a real life logical example haha! :)

Comment: How can anyone answer your question about code being improvable if he can't see the code, so can't understand what you need to improve, make cleaner?

Comment: There is a code block? I want that code to be improved? That's obvious right

Comment: Ah, okay, did you mean, that you have `.getOrElse("")` twice? That wasn't obvious.

Comment: I would like to have Options formatted nicely in a String, without using getOrElse("") if possible. The first comment below gives a neat example!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define an "extension method":

```
implicit class StringOptionOps(val x: Option[String]) extends AnyVal {
  def getOrEmpty = x.getOrElse("")
  // any other methods you want to add to Option[String]
}
```

and/or [customize string interpolation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html) to handle `Option`s as you want (not tested):

```
implicit class StringOptionInterp(val sc: StringContext) {
  def my(args: Any*) = {
    val args1 = args.map {
      case None => ""
      case Some(x) => x
      case x => x
    }
    sc.s(args1: _*)
  }
}

// println(my"some ${Some("string")} none $None") -> some string none
```

Comment: Thanks, String interpolation customization is new to me!

Comment: @JonathanCrosmer No, that would be an implicit conversion from `Option[String]` to `String` (which I very much don't recommend).

Comment: You're right, I misread the code; sorry! (deleted incorrect comment)

Answer (score 3):

This is a generalization of Alexey's solution–an application of the *pimp-my-library* pattern.

By slight abuse of the `CanBuildFrom` implicits, it is possible to write a generic extension method `orEmpty` that applies to options that wrap a collection type.

What is basically needed is a way of getting hold on an empty instance for some wrapped type. This can also be done using `Monoid.empty` in [scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz). The advantage of the `CanBuildFrom` solution is that it doesn't rely on external dependencies.

```
implicit class RichOpt[A](opt: Option[A]) {
    import collection.generic.CanBuildFrom

    def orEmpty[To >: A](implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[A,_,To]): To =
        opt.getOrElse(cbf().result())
}

//---------  Examples --------------

println("some seq: " + (None: Option[Seq[Int]]).orEmpty)
//>some seq: List()

println("none seq: " + (Some(Seq(1,2,3))).orEmpty)
//>none seq: List(1, 2, 3)


println("some range: " + (Some(1 to 3)).orEmpty)
//>some range: Range(1, 2, 3)

println("none range: " + (None: Option[Range]).orEmpty)
//>none range: Vector()


println("some string: " + Some("abc").orEmpty)
//>some string: abc

println("none string: " + (None: Option[String]).orEmpty)
//>none string:
```

Comment: Sweet, I've been finding myself doing this kind of stuff, never knew it actually is a 'pattern' :-)